# ¿Como agregar o quitar un etiqueta html desde JQUERY dependiendo de una función?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

En `JS` tengo el siguiente código:

```
$('#botones').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success hvr-float-shadow pull-right" style="position: relative; bottom: 3px; border-radius: 20px;background: teal; border-color: teal;" onclick="LoadDataEvaluados()"> Evaluado </button>'
                                + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger hvr-float-shadow pull-right"  style="position: relative; bottom: 3px;right: 20px; border-radius: 20px;" onclick="LoadDataNoEvaluados()">No Evaluado</button>');
```

Como se ve, cada `botón` tiene un `onclick` que corresponde a `funciones diferentes`, la idea es que dependiendo a cada `función` se pueda agregar o quitar una columna de una tabla...

**HTML**

```
 <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Cédula</th>
   <th>Nombre</th>
   <th>Apellido</th>
   <th>resultados</th>
 </tr>
(Esta tabla se encuentra en el html)
```

Es decir que cuando se oprima el `botón 'evaluados'` que en este caso contiene la `función LoadDataEvaluados();` **pueda agregar abajo** de la etiqueta o columna `<th>resultados<th>` esta `<th>detalle<th>` **en caso contrario** pues que **no muestre**   `<th>detalle<th>`

Agradeceria el interes. (no podria intentar ocultar esa columna ya que el datatables arrojaria un error.)

Comment: quieres hacer algo como [este ejemplo de datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html)?

Comment: Hola @JuankGlezz, No, es muy distinto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para añadir elementos utiliza el método *append* y para eliminarlos el *remove*.

Ten en cuenta que en el siguiente ejemplo únicamente añado y elimino la cabecera, en la práctica deberías hacerlo con las celdas de todas las filas. Utilizando selectores de jQuery no deberías tener problema.

```js
function LoadDataEvaluados(){
  var $cabecera = $('.cabecera');
  if ($cabecera.find('.detalle').length===0){
    $cabecera.append($('<th class="detalle">Detalle</th>'));
  }
}

function LoadDataNoEvaluados(){
  var $cabecera = $('.cabecera');
  $cabecera.find('.detalle').remove();
}

$('#botones').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success hvr-float-shadow pull-right"  onclick="LoadDataEvaluados()"> Evaluado </button>'
                                + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger hvr-float-shadow pull-right" onclick="LoadDataNoEvaluados()">No Evaluado</button>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="botones"></div>

<table>
 <tr class="cabecera">
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Cédula</th>
   <th>Nombre</th>
   <th>Apellido</th>
   <th>resultados</th>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bueno, pienso que lo que quieres es que no se oculte, y solo no se escriba en el documento. bueno, yo lo haria de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#botones').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success hvr-float-shadow pull-right" style="position: relative; bottom: 3px; border-radius: 20px;background: teal; border-color: teal;" onclick="LoadDataEvaluados()"> Evaluado </button>'
                                + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger hvr-float-shadow pull-right"  style="position: relative; bottom: 3px;right: 20px; border-radius: 20px;" onclick="LoadDataNoEvaluados()">No Evaluado</button>');
})
function LoadDataEvaluados(){
  $('#tblDocumentoHeader').html('<tr>'+
   '<th>ID</th>'+
   '<th>Cédula</th>'+
   '<th>Nombre</th>'+
   '<th>Apellido</th>'+
   '<th>resultados</th>'+
 '</tr>');
}

function LoadDataNoEvaluados(){
  $('#tblDocumentoHeader').html('<tr>'+
   '<th>ID</th>'+
   '<th>Cédula</th>'+
   '<th>Nombre</th>'+
   '<th>Apellido</th>'+
 '</tr>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="botones"></div>
 <div id="tblDocumento">
  <table>
    <thead id="tblDocumentoHeader">
    </thead>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: es añadir una cabecera "detalles" no quitar y poner "resultados".

Answer (score 1):

Validen con este por favor. Saludos

http://www.cubicfactory.com/jseditor/

HTML

```
<body>    

<div id="main">   

<input type="button" id="btAdd" value="Añadir Elemento" class="bt" />     

<input type="button" id="btRemove" value="Eliminar Elemento" class="bt" />    

<input type="button" id="btRemoveAll" value="Eliminar Todo" class="bt" /><br />     

</div>   

</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

var iCnt = 0;     

// Crear un elemento div añadiendo estilos CSS    

var container = $(document.createElement('div')).css({     

padding: '5px', margin: '20px', width: '170px', border: '1px dashed',     

borderTopColor: '#999', borderBottomColor: '#999',     

borderLeftColor: '#999', borderRightColor: '#999' 


}); 




$('#btAdd').click(function() { 


if (iCnt <= 19) { 


iCnt = iCnt + 1; 





// Añadir caja de texto. 


$(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' + 


'value="Elemento de Texto ' + iCnt + '" />'); 





if (iCnt == 1) { 


var divSubmit = $(document.createElement('div')); 


$(divSubmit).append('<input type=button class="bt" onclick="GetTextValue()"' + 


'id=btSubmit value=Enviar />'); 





} 





$('#main').after(container, divSubmit); 


} 


else { //se establece un limite para añadir elementos, 20 es el limite 





$(container).append('<label>Limite Alcanzado</label>'); 


$('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt-disable'); 


$('#btAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 





} 


}); 





$('#btRemove').click(function() { // Elimina un elemento por click 


if (iCnt != 0) { $('#tb' + iCnt).remove(); iCnt = iCnt - 1; } 





if (iCnt == 0) { $(container).empty(); 





$(container).remove(); 


$('#btSubmit').remove(); 


$('#btAdd').removeAttr('disabled'); 


$('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt') 





} 


}); 





$('#btRemoveAll').click(function() { // Elimina todos los elementos del contenedor 





$(container).empty(); 


$(container).remove(); 


$('#btSubmit').remove(); iCnt = 0; 


$('#btAdd').removeAttr('disabled'); 


$('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt'); 





}); 


}); 





// Obtiene los valores de los textbox al dar click en el boton "Enviar" 


var divValue, values = ''; 





function GetTextValue() { 





$(divValue).empty(); 


$(divValue).remove(); values = ''; 





$('.input').each(function() { 


divValue = $(document.createElement('div')).css({ 


padding:'5px', width:'200px' 


}); 


values += this.value + '<br />' 


}); 





$(divValue).append('<p><b>Tus valores añadidos</b></p>' + values); 


$('body').append(divValue);  


}
```

---------------este es el css

```
body { 


font: 13px verdana; 


font-weight: normal; 


}
```

Comment: Si creas un programa ejecutable será mas explicativo

Comment: Peguenlo todo en cualquier simulador de código y verán como trabaja.

Comment: o puedes hacerlo tu, ya que en [es.so] tenemos la herramienta y asi tienes una publicacion de mayor calidad

Comment: Les paso el código para que puedan ver como trabaja.  http://codepen.io/HostDimeColombia/pen/ByOOLr

Comment: Pero para que mandar a alguien a otro lugar cuando pueden pulsar ejecutar bajo tu respuesta...?

Comment: No es mi post, solo es un link, no es mio. Déjenme buscar otro y los cargo para que lo vean. ACLARO, no es mi post.

Comment: Hola @Ric_hc gracias por el interes y por el codigo que trabaja de forma buena, pero parece que has puesto el codigo por ponerlo y ya pero no se esta basando al requirimiento.

Comment: He actializado mi respuesta, si alguien lo necesita con mucho gusto. No busco puntuaciones, sino apoyar a los demás tal cual me lo han brindado. Saludos, mil disculpas a los que se sintieron ofendidos.

Comment: @Ric_hc: Apreciamos tu participación. Es importante señalar que hay lineamientos sobre cómo responder. En [answer] se indica textualmente `Cualquier respuesta que encamine al los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudara siempre y cuando menciones limitaciones, supuestos, o simplificaciones en tu respuesta.La brevedad es aceptable pero respuestas robustas son las mejores.`

Answer (score 1):

Existen dos formas

document.createElement("etiqueta"); donde "etiqueta" sera el nombre de la etiqueta que uses

```
var Titulo = document.createElement("h1");
Titulo.setAttribute("id", "Tit_Serv_0"+num_id);
Titulo.setAttribute("class", "Titulo-Servicio");
Titulo.innerHTML = resp.data["0"][2];
```

Variable.innerHTML; puedes agregar un texto completo con innerHTML directamente a tu pagina, pero los cambios que se hagan no se captaran dentro del js, entiendes? en pocas palabras, agregas los elementos, mas funcionalidades no seral tan facil de tratar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="Valor">
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me </p>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
getElementById("Valor").innerHTML = 
"<h1 id='Tit_Serv_0' class='Titulo-Servicio'>Dato</h1>";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Suerte

Answer (score 1):

Este es un ejemplo Ocultando / Mostrando el encabezado **Resultados** usando la librería de datatanbles.net, pero primero he puesto en el `<thead>` de la tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
    <th>Resultado</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Ahora en la declaración del plugin lo he dejado de esta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": [6],// estoy indicando que resultado siempre va estar oculto
      "visible": false
    }]
  });
});
```

en las funciones de los botones he puesto lo siguiente:

```
var column = table.column(6);//indico que es Resultado
column.visible(true);//y se va a mostrar al presionar, cambiara a false si se va ocultar
```

Ejemplo funcional

```js
$('#botones').html('' +
  '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success hvr-float-shadow pull-right" style="position: relative; bottom: 3px; border-radius: 20px;background: teal; border-color: teal;" onclick="LoadDataEvaluados()"> Evaluado </button>' +
  '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger hvr-float-shadow pull-right"  style="position: relative; bottom: 3px;right: 20px; border-radius: 20px;" onclick="LoadDataNoEvaluados()">No Evaluado</button>');
var table;

function LoadDataEvaluados() {
  var column = table.column(6);
  // Toggle the visibility
  column.visible(true);
}

function LoadDataNoEvaluados() {
  var column = table.column(6);
  // Toggle the visibility
  column.visible(false);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": [6],
      "visible": false
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div id='botones'></div>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Resultado</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Este ejemplo hace lo que deseas pero no te permitirá ordenarlos

```js
$('#botones').html('' +
  '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success hvr-float-shadow pull-right" style="position: relative; bottom: 3px; border-radius: 20px;background: teal; border-color: teal;" onclick="LoadDataEvaluados()"> Evaluado </button>' +
  '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger hvr-float-shadow pull-right"  style="position: relative; bottom: 3px;right: 20px; border-radius: 20px;" onclick="LoadDataNoEvaluados()">No Evaluado</button>');

var table;

function LoadDataEvaluados() {
  $('table thead tr').append(
    $('<th/>', {
      text: 'Resultados'
    })
  );
  $('#example').DataTable({
    'responsive': true,
    "retrieve": true,
    "destroy": true
  });
}

function LoadDataNoEvaluados() {
  $('table thead tr th:last').remove();
  $('#example').DataTable({
    'responsive': true,
    "retrieve": true,
    "destroy": true
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  table = $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div id='botones'></div>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```